# CORS issue on ESP32 with nodemcu lua

Tags: lua, esp32, nodemcu

I want to create Esp32 based server and wanted to implement local REST api's so I took https://github.com/abobija/api32 help and written some api's everything working with chrome/postman but when tried to use with my mobile app not able to get the response but can able to post the data to esp32.
I'm getting this error
***Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.0.10/' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.***

my code is

```
    Title          : Library for easy way of creating HTTP JSON Api Service for ESP32
    Author         : Alija Bobija
    Author-Website : https://abobija.com
    GitHub Repo    : https://github.com/abobija/api32
    
    Dependencies:
        - sjson
        - encoder
]]

local Api32 = {}

local function str_starts_with(haystack, needle)
    return haystack:sub(1, #needle) == needle
end

local function str_ends_with(str, ending)
   return ending == "" or str:sub(-#ending) == ending
end

local function str_split(inputstr, sep)
    if sep == nil then sep = "%s" end
    local result = {}
    for str in inputstr:gmatch("([^"..sep.."]+)") do table.insert(result, str) end
    
    return result
end

local function json_parse(json_str)
    local ok
    local result
    ok, result = pcall(sjson.decode, json_str)

    if ok then return result end
    return nil
end

local function json_stringify(table)
    local ok
    local json
    ok, json = pcall(sjson.encode, table)
    
    if ok then return json end
    return nil
end

local function get_http_header_value(hname, hlines)
    for _, hline in pairs(hlines) do
        if str_starts_with(hline:lower(), hname:lower()) then
            local colon_index = hline:find(':')

            if colon_index ~= nil then
                return hline:sub(colon_index + 2)
            end
        end
    end

    return nil
end

local function get_auth_from_http_header(hlines)
    local auth_line = get_http_header_value('Authorization', hlines)

    if auth_line == nil then return nil end

    local parts = str_split(auth_line)

    if #parts == 2 and parts[1]:lower() == 'basic' then
        local key = parts[2]
        parts = nil

        local ok
        local decoded_key
        ok, decoded_key = pcall(encoder.fromBase64, key)
        
        key = nil

        if ok then
            parts = str_split(decoded_key, ':')
            decoded_key = nil

            if #parts == 2 then
                return {
                    user = parts[1],
                    pwd  = parts[2]
                }
            end
        end
    end
    
    return nil
end

local function parse_http_header(request, params)
    local options = {
        parse_auth = false
    }

    if params ~= nil then
        if params.parse_auth ~= nil then options.parse_auth = params.parse_auth end
    end

    local hlines = str_split(request, "\r\n")

    if #hlines > 0 then
        local hline1_parts = str_split(hlines[1])
        
        if #hline1_parts == 3 and hline1_parts[3] == 'HTTP/1.1' then
            local result = {
                method = hline1_parts[1],
                path   = hline1_parts[2],
                std    = hline1_parts[3]
            }

            hline1_parts = nil
            
            result.content_length = get_http_header_value('Content-Length', hlines)

            if options.parse_auth then
                result.auth = get_auth_from_http_header(hlines)
            end
            
            hlines = nil

            if result.content_length ~= nil then
                result.content_length = tonumber(result.content_length)
            end

            return result
        end
    end

    return nil
end

-- Extends one level only
local function extend(tbl, with)
    if with ~= nil then
        for k, v in pairs(with) do
            if tbl[k] == nil then
                tbl[k] = with[k]
            end
        end
    end

    return tbl
end

Api32.create = function(conf)
    local self = extend({
        http_body_min = 10,
        http_body_max = 512,
        port          = 80,
        auth          = nil
    }, conf)
    
    local endpoints = {}
    
    self.on = function(method, path, handler)
        table.insert(endpoints, {
            method  = method,
            path    = path,
            handler = handler
        })
        
        return self
    end

    self.on_get = function(path, handler)
        return self.on('GET', path, handler)
    end

    self.on_post = function(path, handler)
        return self.on('POST', path, handler)
    end
    
    local get_endpoint = function(method, path)
        for _, ep in pairs(endpoints) do
            if ep.method == method and ep.path == path then return ep end
        end

        return nil
    end
    
    local srv = net.createServer(net.TCP, 30)

    local sending = false
    local http_header = nil
    local http_req_body_buffer = nil

    local function stop_rec()
        sending = false
        http_header = nil
        http_req_body_buffer = nil
    end

    local is_authorized = function()
        return self.auth == nil or (
            http_header ~= nil
            and http_header.auth ~= nil
            and self.auth.user == http_header.auth.user
            and self.auth.pwd == http_header.auth.pwd
        )
    end
    
    local function parse_http_request(sck)
        local res = {}
        local stream_file = nil
        
        local send = function(_sck)
            sending = true

            local close_socket = false
            
            if #res > 0 then
                _sck:send(table.remove(res, 1))
            elseif stream_file ~= nil then
                local line = stream_file:readline()
                
                if line ~= nil then
                    _sck:send(line)
                else
                    stream_file:close()
                    stream_file = nil
                    close_socket = true
                end
            else
                close_socket = true
            end

            if close_socket then
                sending = false
                _sck:close()
                res = nil
            end
        end
        
        sck:on('sent', send)
        
        local response_status = '200 OK'
        local content_type = 'application/json'
        local response_body = nil
        
        res[1] = 'HTTP/1.1 '
        res[2] = 'Content-Type: CTYPE; charset=UTF-8\r\n'
        
        if http_header == nil then
            response_status = '400 Bad Request'
        else
            if not is_authorized() then
                response_status = '401 Unauthorized'
                res[#res + 1]   = 'WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="User Visible Realm", charset="UTF-8"\r\n'
            else
                local ep = get_endpoint(http_header.method, http_header.path)
                
                if ep == nil then
                    response_status = '404 Not Found'
                else
                    http_header = nil
                    
                    if type(ep.handler) == 'function' then -- custom handler
                        local jreq = json_parse(http_req_body_buffer)
                        http_req_body_buffer = nil
                        local jres = ep.handler(jreq)
                        jreq = nil
                        response_body = json_stringify(jres)
                        jres = nil
                    elseif type(ep.handler) == 'string' then -- static file
                        -- ep.handler is filename in this case
                        http_req_body_buffer = nil

                        if not file.exists(ep.handler) then
                            response_status = '404 Not Found'
                        else
                            if str_ends_with(ep.handler, 'html') then
                                content_type = 'text/html'
                            end
                            
                            stream_file = file.open(ep.handler)
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
        
        res[1] = res[1] .. response_status .. "\r\n"
        res[2] = res[2]:gsub('CTYPE', content_type)
        res[#res + 1] = "\r\n"

        if response_body ~= nil then
            res[#res + 1] = response_body
            response_body = nil
        end
        
        stop_rec()
        send(sck)
    end
    
    local on_receive = function(sck, data)
        if sending then return end
        
        if http_header == nil then
            local eof_head = data:find("\r\n\r\n")
            local head_data = nil
            
            if eof_head ~= nil then
                head_data = data:sub(1, eof_head - 1)
                http_req_body_buffer = data:sub(eof_head + 4)
            end
            
            data = nil

            if head_data ~= nil then
                http_header = parse_http_header(head_data, {
                    parse_auth = self.auth ~= nil
                })
                
                head_data = nil
            end

            if http_header ~= nil then
                if http_header.content_length == nil
                    or http_header.content_length < self.http_body_min
                    or http_header.content_length > self.http_body_max then
                    -- It seems like request body is too short, too big or does not exist at all.
                    
                    -- Parse request immediatelly
                    return parse_http_request(sck)
                end
            else
                -- Received some data which does not represent the http header.
                -- Let's parse it anyway because error 400 shoud be sent back to the client
                
                return parse_http_request(sck)
            end
        end

        if data ~= nil and http_header ~= nil then
            -- Buffering request body
            
            if http_req_body_buffer == nil then
                http_req_body_buffer = data
            else
                http_req_body_buffer = http_req_body_buffer .. data
            end
        end

        -- Check if body has received
        if http_req_body_buffer ~= nil then
            local http_body_len = http_req_body_buffer:len()
            
            if (http_header.content_length ~= nil and http_body_len >= http_header.content_length)
                or http_body_len >= self.http_body_max then
                -- Received enough bytes of request body.
                
                return parse_http_request(sck)
            end
        end
    end

    srv:listen(self.port, function(conn)
        stop_rec()
    
        conn:on('receive', on_receive)
        conn:on('disconnection', stop_rec)
    end)

    return self
end

return Api32
```

and another module api32local

```
local M = {}
_G[moduleName] = M
if api == nil then
        api = require('api32')
        .create()
        .on_get('/', function() return{message = 'Welcome to the API32!'} end)
.on_post("/house_lamp",function(jreq,raw_data)
            if jreq==nil or raw_data==nil then return end
            gpio.write(BLUE_LED, jreq.state)
            print("led Post Command")
            return{"lamp_status updated"}
        end)
end
return M
```

for wifi

```
wifi.mode(wifi.SOFTAP)
    cfg={}
    cfg.ip='192.168.0.10'
    cfg.netmask='255.255.255.0'
    cfg.gateway='192.168.0.1'
    cfg.dns='8.8.8.8'
    wifi.ap.setip(cfg)
    wifi.ap.config({
        ssid = "****",
        pwd = "*123456#",
        auth=wifi.AUTH_OPEN,
        auto  = false
    })
    Myapi32_init=require'api32local'
    wifi.ap.on("sta_connected", function(event, info) Myapi32_init.init_api32() print("MAC_id"..info.mac,"Name"..info.id) end)
    wifi.start()
```

please help me debugging issue. Can't able to understand where to use cross origin headers and how, and about preflight concept which are importent for angular based android app to communicate locally(without internet) through http with ESP32

Answer (score 0):

The CORS policy is a safety measure that is implemented in your web browser. The intention is to prevent an arbitrary website (in this case your page running on http://localhost) to POST data to an API on a *different* origin (in this case your ESP on http://192.168.0.10/).

Your ESP can instruct the browser to disable this safety precaution by adding the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to your response. Note that the browser first sends an OPTIONS request to see if your API allows the POST before actually submitting the POST. So, you have to respond to the OPTIONS request first.

In my code (which uses ESP8266WebServer.h) the solution looks like this:

```
void handleApi()
{
  if(server.method() == HTTP_OPTIONS)
  {
    server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*"); // Allow CORS (preflight response)  
    server.send(200, "text/plain", "" );
    return;
  }
  
  // Assume POST.
  // Do something with data.

  server.sendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
  server.send ( 200, "text/plain", "{}");
}
```

Please be aware that disabling the CORS policy allows *every* page to make requests to your API. This introduces a security risk enabling malicious pages (or advertisements) on the internet to abuse your API. For more details, see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS